# Isoceles Triangle Problem

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

**Given**

ABC is an Isosceles Triangle with $AB = AC$

$$DA = DC$$

Circle with Center $D$ and Radius $DA$ intersect $BC$ at $E$

**To Prove**

$$BE = CE$$

Comment: You need to show your attempt at this problem so we can help you solve this.

Comment: I attempted but ending up running out of information but my friend told me it's complete

Comment: The angle $\angle{AEC}$ is rectangular because  AC is diameter so the arc subtended is of $180^{\circ}$. In such a case AE is  median of the isosceles triangle $\triangle{ABC}$.

Comment: @Piquito That's the answer I was searching... Put it as an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: It is not necessary, Dear Friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E$ is the intersection of the circle centered at $D$ with radius $AD$, hence , a point on the circle. So the distance between $D$ and $E$ is exactly the radius of the circle. Thus, $DE=CD$ and $△DEC$ is also an isosceles triangle, and $∠ACB = ∠DCE$.

From the property of isosceles triangles we can say that
$$
∠ACB = ∠ABC,\ ∠DEC = ∠DCE,
$$
which implies
$$
∠ABC = ∠DEC.
$$
By AA post, $$△ABC \sim△DEC.$$

Note that$$
2DC=AC \Longrightarrow \frac{BC}{EC} =  \frac{AC}{DC} = 2 \Longrightarrow 2EC=BC,
$$
so points $B, E, C$ are collinear points and $BC=BE+EC$. Therefore $BE=CE$.

I'm a student so I'm not that confident on my answer but I hope it can help.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Comment: its my first time answering a question. I tried using the latex code but it's not working.